# Getting masked area to be transparent?

Tags: c++, opencv, transparent, image-manipulation, mask

So far i have managed to use masks and get the second image from the first. But what i want is the black area in second image to be transparent (i.e the output i an trying to get is the third image) Here is the code so far. Please advice me on this.

EDIT: Third one is from photoshop

```
    //imwrite parameters
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
compression_params.push_back(100);

//reading image to be masked
image = imread(main_img, -1);

//CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR

namedWindow("output", WINDOW_NORMAL);
//imshow("output", image);

//Creating mask image with same size as original image
Mat mask(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));


// Create Polygon from vertices
ROI_Vertices.push_back(Point2f(float(3112),float(58)));
ROI_Vertices.push_back(Point2f(float(3515),float(58)));
ROI_Vertices.push_back(Point2f(float(3515),float(1332)));
ROI_Vertices.push_back(Point2f(float(3112),float(958)));

approxPolyDP(ROI_Vertices, ROI_Poly, 1, true);

// Fill polygon white
fillConvexPoly(mask, &ROI_Poly[0] , ROI_Poly.size(), 255, 8, 0);                 

//imshow("output", mask);

// Create new image for result storage
imageDest = cvCreateMat(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC4);

// Cut out ROI and store it in imageDest
image.copyTo(imageDest, mask);

imwrite("masked.jpeg", imageDest, compression_params);
imshow("output", imageDest);

cvWaitKey(0);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can [blend](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) two images in OpenCV and use weightings in order to make it transparent.

Comment: @GPPK thanks for the reply. Yes.  For that i must have a transparent image first. Here what i want is to obtain a image like third one from the first one. Is it possible with blending ? If so can you please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by first setting its alpha value to 0 of the regions that you want to make them fully transparent (255 for others), and then save it to PNG.

To set the alpha value of pixel-(x,y), it can be done:

```
image.at<cv::Vec4b>(y, x)[3] = 0;
```

PS: you need to convert it to 4-channel format first if the image is not currently. For example:

```
cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2BGRA);
```

---

**Updated:** It will be easier if you have already computed the mask for the ROI region, where you can simply merge it with the original image (assume having 3 channels) to get the final result. Like:

```
cv::Mat mask; // 0 for transparent regions, 255 otherwise (serve as the alpha channel)

std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::split(image, channels);

channels.push_back(mask);
cv::Mat result;
cv::merge(channels, result);
```

Comment: Thank You. Can you please explain me a bit more. I'm just a beginner to OpenCV. How can i apply alpha value changes to a region at once ? Is it done using the same way as of masking ?